# Is a future safe to pass to a detached thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Is passing a `std::future` to a detached instance of `std::thread` a safe operation? I know that underneath, the `std::future` has state in a shared_ptr which it shares with a `std::promise`. Here is an example.

```
int main()
{
    std::promise<void> p;
    std::thread( [f = p.get_future()]() {
        if ( f.wait_for( std::chrono::seconds( 2 ) ) == std::future_status::ready ) 
        {
            return;
        }

        std::terminate();
    } ).detach();

    // wait for some operation

    p.set_value();
}
```

There is a potential error case in the above code where the lambda is executed after the main thread exits. Does the shared state remain after the main thread exits?

Comment: How do you know that shared_ptr is used for the shared state? Is that in the standard? Cause I don't see it and I think it's an implementation detail. And so your code is most definitely not safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[basic.start.term]/6** If there is a use of a standard library object or function not permitted within signal handlers (21.10) that does not happen before (4.7) completion of destruction of objects with static storage duration and execution of `std::atexit` registered functions (21.5), the program has undefined behavior.

Per **[basic.start.main]/5**, returning from `main` has the effect of calling `std::exit`, which does destroy objects with static storage duration and execute `std::atexit` registered functions. Therefore, I believe your example exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Can you add to your answer why objects with static storage duration being destroyed at `std::atexit` is relevant to the example? Where is the state of the `std::future` being stored and where is it stated in the standard?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Perhaps there is no object with static duration, and destroying them is a no-op. What matters is, there is a point in the execution of the main thread when all such objects (perhaps none) are destroyed, and all `atexit` handlers (perhaps none) are executed - a moment right before "control is returned to the host environment". You have a second thread running that calls standard library functions - it doesn't matter which ones, it's not specific to `std::future` - and those calls don't happen-before that special moment. Whereupon the program exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr):

> In a typical implementation, std::shared_ptr holds only two pointers:
>   - the stored pointer (one returned by get());
>   - a pointer to control block.
>   The control block is a dynamically-allocated object...

Given this information, I wouldn't think that the termination of the main thread is going to affect the `shared_ptr` in the worker thread.